# how to use inverse in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

[how to use ~ operator ]

I have a structure say `Alpha`.  I know the value of element inside `Alpha` (say `a`) which can be `0` or `1` - I want the other element of same structure to take inverse value of Alpha.a. For example:

```
if Alpha.a = 1
then Alpha.b = 0
```

and vice versa

I have tried:

```
Alpha.b = ~ (Alpha.a)
```

But unfortunately it doesnt work - when `Alpha.a` is `1`, `Alpha.b` gets set to `254`

Any ideas?

Thanks and regards,

SamPrat

Comment: **Why doesn't it work? What happens?**

Comment: HI guys , i am eager to know why  my question is down voted so that from next time I will rem my mistake?

Comment: When you ask a question, you should supply as many details as possible.  Saying "it doesn't work" is utterly useless.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. I will keep in mind from next time

Comment: it's a bit funny that many newbie questions are supposed to be detailed(yup, that's right), but answers are fine if it just works, even without any logic behind it :) BTW, Martin's editing of the original question was good!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use XOR operator:

```
Alpha.b = Alpha.a ^ 1;
```

Answer (score 41):

In C, `true` is represented by 1, and `false` by 0. However, in a comparison, any non-false value is treated is true.

The `!` operator does *boolean* inversion, so !0 is 1 and !1 is 0.

The `~` operator, however, does *bitwise* inversion, where every bit in the value is replaced with its inverse. So ~0 is 0xffffffff (-1). ~1 is 0xfffffffe (-2). (And both -1 and -2 are considered as true, which is probably what's confusing you.)

What you want is `!`, instead of `~`.

Answer (score 6):

The `~` operator negates each individual bit. For example, assume that `Alpha.a` is an `unsigned char`. Then `~1` would read, in binary as, ~00000001, and the result would be 11111110 (again, in binary), which is the same as 254 in decimal and 0xFE in hex.

As others have suggested, use `!Alpha.a` or `Alpha.a ^ 1`.

Answer (score 4):

A nice cross-platform cross language solution to this common problem is:

```
Alpha.b = 1 - Alpha.a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `~` as this will turn `00000000` into `11111111` rather than `00000001` as I think you're expecting.

If you have bools you can use:

```
Alpha.b = !(Alpha.a)
```

but if not you may have to use if / else logic:

```
if (Alpha.a == 0)
{
    Alpha.b = 1;
}
else
{
    Alpha.b = 0;
}
```

Comment: I ma trying to build message so if else is not reommended at this stage of my code

Answer (score 1):

What about a postoperational bitmask?

using unsigned chars looking for bit0:

```
b = 0x01u & ( ~a );
```

or even

```
b = a ^ 0x01u;
```

or for "Boolean-Thinkers" ( be aware TRUE and FALSE may differ from 0/1 ! if you want it "real boolean" you should use TRUE and FALSE if defined.)

```
b = (1 != a)?(0u):(1u);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You want to use another operator.  Specifically !

```
Alpha.b = !Alpha.a
```

Since the values are zero or one, it is much simplier.

Comment: **Why not? What happens?**